# Error message nutch eclipse

Tags: eclipse, nutch

I am trying to build nutch 1.4 from the source code within eclipse env. Everything is ok but I receive an error message in class org.apache.nutch.util.domain.TopLevelDomain.java that says

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. 
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

What could be the reason when Object is the main class and Libraries for JRE are included.

Answer (score 0):

Your project needs to point to a valid JRE, which itself needs to be properly set up n the Installed JREs preference page.

Comment: Yes you were right. By unknown reason I have removed the libs for JRE. I added JRE libs and the errors disappeared. 10x.